# How to matching two Dictionaries after comparing the index values

Tags: python

I want the key in the resulting dict to be the key in dict1 (i.e. k1) and the value in the resulting dict is the key from dict2 (k2) that has a value v2 equal to the value for k1 in dict1 i.e. v1 (v2==v1)
First dict1

```
dict1 = {
  "a": "121",
  "b": "132",
  "c": "312",
  "d": "434",
  "e": "564",
  "f": "663",    
}
```

The second one is -

```
dict2 = {
  "a": "312",
  "b": "121",
  "c": "564",
  "d": "663",
  "e": "434",
  "f": "132",    
}
```

The result should look like this -

```
Results = {
  "a": "b",
  "b": "f",
  "c": "a",
  "d": "e",
  "e": "c",
  "f": "d",    
}
```

Dict is key-value pair. I would like to compare the value of dict1 with the value of dict2 and print the key of dict2

Comment: Are the results meant to be random?

Comment: Do I get it right that you want the key in the resulting dict to be the key in dict1 (i.e. k1) and the value in the resulting dict is the key from dict2 (k2) that has value v2 equal to value for k1 in dict1 i.e. v1 (v2==v1)? Are the values in d2 unique (they have to be)?

Comment: @PeterWood No, It should be the keys of dict2

Comment: Please explain in detail how you get `Results` from `dict1` and `dict2`, because I haven't the faintest idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a new dict that swap key and value from dict2. Note that your requirement imply the values in dict2 are unique and can serve as keys.
Then

```
dict1 = {
  "0": "1",
  "1": "4",
  "2": "5",
  "3": "6",
  "4": "7",
  "5": "8",    
}

dict2 = {
  "0": "6",
  "1": "8",
  "2": "4",
  "3": "1",
  "4": "5",
  "5": "7",    
}

dict3 = {val:key for key, val in dict2.items()}
result =  {key:dict3.get(val) for key, val in dict1.items()}
print(result)
```